# Counting occurrences of a field across multiple lines

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I am trying to count the cumulative sum of a column and return the answer in the last column of the output file.

Here is an example input file

```
a  
a  
a  
b  
b  
c  
d  
d
```

Here is the desired output

```
a    1  
a    2  
a    3  
b    1  
b    2   
c    1   
d    1  
d    2
```

I would like the solution to be able to run from the Unix command line.

Comment: Very easy with associative array. Better say what you've tried (and where you get stuck) than throwing the question at us.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. First you say you want the answer in the last column (try  `sort "inputfile"| uniq -c`) or do you want to have what you showed with `desired output` ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Your solution using sort and uniq gives me a tally of each of the elements. However, I was looking for cumulative count as shown in the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

PREV=""
COUNT="0"

cat ${1} | while read LINE ; do
   if [ "${LINE}" == "${PREV}" ] ; then
     (( COUNT++ ))
   else
     (( COUNT=1 ))
   fi
   echo "${LINE} ${COUNT}"
   PREV="${LINE}"
done
```

Save this script and run: ./script.sh your_input_file

Comment: Thank you for this solution. It has solved my problem and showed me how I can do something similar using awk.